# How to make Sum of grand child field and show it on Parent record

Tags: apex, trigger, aggregateresult

my requirement is whenever OpportunityLineItem Created makes the sum of quantity available for Opportunity and also take care of rest of Opportunity for particular Account and update Total Sales Quantity.

Here is the code I'm Coming up with.
**Can Someone suggest any other Linear Way or my Code is fine?**

```
public class OpportunityLineItemHandler {
    public static void getTotalSalesQuantity(List<OpportunityLineItem> newOpportunityLineItemList){
        Set<Id> ParentOppIdsSet = new Set<Id>();
        for(OpportunityLineItem objOppLine : newOpportunityLineItemList){
            ParentOppIdsSet.add(objOppLine.OpportunityId);
        }
        Map<Id,Decimal> NoOfOpportunityQuantity = new Map<Id,Decimal>();
        for(AggregateResult ar : [SELECT OpportunityId,SUM(Quantity)sumOfQuantity FROM OpportunityLineItem GROUP BY OpportunityId ]){
            NoOfOpportunityQuantity.put( (Id)ar.get('OpportunityId') , (Decimal)ar.get('sumOfQuantity') );
        }
        
        Set<Id> grandParentAccount = new Set<Id>();
        for(Opportunity oppObj : [SELECT Id,AccountId FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN : ParentOppIdsSet]){
            
             grandParentAccount.add(oppObj.AccountId);
        }
        List<Account> accountsToBeupdated = new List<Account>();
        for(Account objAcc : [SELECT Id, Total_Sales_Quantity__c,(SELECT Id FROM Opportunities) FROM Account WHERE Id IN : grandParentAccount]){
            Decimal totalSalesbyAccountId = 0;
            for(Opportunity objOpp : objAcc.Opportunities){
                if(NoOfOpportunityQuantity.containsKey(objOpp.Id)){
                    totalSalesbyAccountId = totalSalesbyAccountId + NoOfOpportunityQuantity.get(objOpp.Id);
                }
            }
            objAcc.Total_Sales_Quantity__c = totalSalesbyAccountId;
            accountsToBeupdated.add(objAcc);
        }
        update accountsToBeupdated;
    }
}
```

Comment: why not use RSF field on Account that rolls up  Opportunity.Quantity__c that is also an RSF of OpportunityLineItem.Quantity?  No code required at all

Comment: @cropredy I know It can be done by Roll-up summary field but in case I'm having this kind of requirement in the future for Lookup Relationship, That's why I want to know that is a good approach for apex or not.

Comment: Use DLRS for lookup relationships.  Widely used and accepted as best practice

Comment: @cropredy Thanks for suggesting this wonderful tool!!

Comment: There's also [apex rollup](https://github.com/jamessimone/apex-rollup) as well now as another option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your particular use case, the easiest thing to do is:

- Define a RSF field `Opportunity.Quantity__c` thats rolls up `OpportunityLineItem.Quantity`
- Define a RSF field `Account.AllOpportunityQuantity__c` that sums `Opportunity.Quantity__c`

No Apex code involved

Should you have lookup relationships to sum over, use the free open source packages which are widely used:

- [Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries](https://github.com/SFDO-Community/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries)
- [Apex Rollup](https://github.com/jamessimone/apex-rollup)